# Buffer over run issue when debugging a c code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 20
#define MAX_BASE 8
#define ROW 9
#define COLUMN_SCORE 12
#define MAX_SKATER 4

typedef struct{
            char  name[MAX];
            int   elements;
            float baseval[MAX_BASE];
            int score[12][MAX_BASE];
            double total_score;
          }SKATER;

int getData(SKATER skater[MAX]);


int main (void)
{
    // Global Declarations
    SKATER skater[MAX_SKATER];
    int num;

    // Function calls
    num = getData(skater);

return 0;
}

/********************************* getData ************************************
Pre:
Post:
*/
int getData(SKATER skater[MAX_SKATER])
{
    // LOcal Declarations
    FILE* fpIn;
    int   i = 0;  
    int   k;
    int   j;
    char  buffer[100]; 

    // Statements
    if((fpIn = fopen("lab6data.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
    printf("File opening error");
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(100);
    }

    while(i < MAX_SKATER && fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, fpIn))
    {
         sscanf(buffer,"%*c%19[^0123456789]%[^\n]", skater[i].name);    
         for(k = 0; k < MAX_BASE; k++)
             printf("loop");
             sscanf(buffer,"%d", &skater[i].elements, skater[i].baseval);
             for(j = 0; j < COLUMN_SCORE; j++)
             {
                sscanf(buffer,"%d", skater[i].score[k][j]);
             }
        i++;        
    }

    fclose(fpIn);
    return i;
}
```

Hi, When I tried to debug this code it shows me the error that buffer was overrun, how do I fix this error? This is the first time that I've encounter this error, also, I'm not sure if  the way that I approach this problem was right? can anyone tell me a way to approach the problem 
so here is the sample data for the problem:

```
PLUSHENKO Evgeni
1 13.0 0 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 
2 7.5 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2
3 6.0 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 1 2 1 2
4 2.3 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
5 3.4 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 2 1
6 2.1 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 1 2 1 1
7 3.1 1 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1
8 3.5 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
```

There are 3 more blocks of data beside this one 
thank for helping

Comment: Looks like `sscanf(buffer,"%d", skater[i].score[k][j]);` should be `sscanf(buffer,"%d", &skater[i].score[k][j]);` (you're missing an `&`).

Comment: I am not sure about what the program does. But as @DCoder says, when you add the miss the missing & everywhere, program runs normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `int score[12][MAX_BASE];` in the struct `SKATER`.But you scanf like this:

```
         for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
         {
            sscanf(buffer,"%d", skater[i].score[k][j]);
         }
```

The index is error.You should change to `sscanf(buffer,"%d", &skater[i].score[j][k]);` and don't miss `&`

`sscanf(buffer,"%d", &skater[i].elements, skater[i].baseval);` change to `sscanf(buffer,"%d %f", &skater[i].elements, skater[i].baseval);`

I think you need read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/).Need passed the point to `sscanf`

Good Luck!